# Visual Studio 2017 mistakenly thinks EF 6 is installed

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I upgraded my ASP.NET Core, EF Core class library solution to Visual Studio 2017.

However when I want to run migrations commands like Add-Migration I get the following warning.

> Both Entity Framework Core and Entity Framework 6 are installed. The Entity Framework Core tools are running. Use 'EntityFramework\Update-Database' for Entity Framework 6.

However I don't have EF 6 installed

My csproj

```
    ...

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Collections" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Linq" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Threading" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net452' ">
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Migrations\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: I expect the error is referring to the tooling being installed, not that both are used in your project.

Comment: Try `EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration` so EF Core tools are used, as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell#using-ef-core-tools-and-ef6-side-by-side

Comment: Regardless of warning, you would be getting EF core commands in PMC. Though if you don't have EF6 installed in project then it should not be giving you warning. Probably a false positive. Can you file an issue at https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework with your project files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can happen if you previously had an EF6 project open in VS. To unload EF6, you can use the following command.

```
Remove-Module EntityFramework
```